# Tooltip position is not working properly in D3 Funnel Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to do a d3 horizontal funnel chart.

Everything is working properly but tooltip position is not working properly it appears at a different location.

Here is my code:

```js
const data = [
                ["L0", 10],
    ["L1", 0],
    ["L2", 5],
    ["L3", 10],
    ["L4", 3],
    ["L5", 10]
                
            ];
            newdata = data.map(function (d,i){
              var new_d = d
              if (new_d[1] == 0){
                 new_d[1] = 0.50
              }
              return new_d
            })
            
            const options = {
                chart: {
                    width: 200,
                    height: 450,
                    bottomWidth: 1 / 2,
                    bottomPinch: 1,
                    
                },
                block: {
                    dynamicSlope: true,
                    dynamicHeight: true,
                    minHeight:50
                    
                    
                    
                },
                label: {
                    enabled: true,
                    fontSize: '18px',
                    fill: '#fff',
                    /* format: '{l}: {f}' */
                   format: function(label, value) {
                    console.log('value', value);
                    if(value ==0.50){
                      var a=0;
                      return label+ ":" + a;
                    }else{
                                          return label+ ":" + value;
                    }
                            
                                    }
                                    },
              tooltip: {
                   enabled: true,
                format: '{l}: {f}'
                } 
            };

            const chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');
            chart.draw(newdata, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel/master/dist/d3-funnel.min.js"></script>
 
 
  <div id="funnel" style="transform: rotate(270deg);height: 539px;width:1px;margin-left:267px;"></div>
```

(from http://jsfiddle.net/3x265bLj/79/)

Comment: very obvious, you rotate your div 270 degrees and your mouse position is relative to a coord system that is **not** rotated. Do the rotation inside the SVG, then your tooltip is readable.

Comment: Please post your code here, rather than linking to an external site; StackOverflow questions should be answerable without having to visit a link or rely on an external site still being active. I've copied your JS Fiddle code for you. Please read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help ensure you get the most out of SO. Thank you!